# java heap space error need complete ini file or command line code

Tags: java, heap-memory

I hate asking this because so many people ask it, but I've yet to see complete answer. I can no longer compile because of the proverbial java heap space out of memory error. my eclipse.ini had only two lines in it originally:

-data
@noDefault

I've tried adding various things like:

-data
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
@noDefault

or 
-data
@noDefault
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m

or

-data
@noDefault
-startup
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-vmargs
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m

I've also tried much longer code additions and other permutations of the above code, and different memory adds like 512m, as per various suggestions on this site. what would be nice is a COMPLETE code listing for the eclipse.ini file for people who had next to nothing in it to start, like me and others with just 2 lines in this file, including instructions on which lines would have to be changed for one's own configuration, for windows (i'm running windows 7 premium).

also using the command line with: 
eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m
 or 
eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XXMaxPermSize=512m
has not worked. i'm willing to run the command line for every eclipse launch if I found a command line sequence that worked.

it would be a shame if coders to spend the research and study time becoming an expert at eclipse.ini file manipulation just to fix the common out of heap space memory error.

Comment: did you get across this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659)?

Comment: I did. it looks pretty messy with lines like: C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow and -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/Prog/Java/eclipse_addons
parts of which would have to be changed for different configs I expect. isn't there something more bare-bones, or something simple from the command line?